# Change response status on spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, error-handling

I'm trying to have a different error message on the frontend when my condition is true, i can't change my status code , it's always 401
if anyone has an idea about how to do it , i'll be grateful

```
 @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String email = request.getParameter("username");
        String lockMessage = bruteForceProtectionService.updateFailedLoginAttempts(email);
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(lockMessage)) {
            response.setStatus(455);
        }
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
```

Comment: Give it a try (instead of the "455" line): `response.sendError(HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE.value(), "455 Method Not Valid in This State");`
Make sure your value is valid in the HttpStatus enum class.

Comment: no it's not working , i tried with many HttpStatus codes, before the code was sended to the browser is 401 but now it's 500  =>  {timestamp: "2022-06-01T19:37:00.757+00:00", status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error",…}
error: "Internal Server Error"
path: "/rest/api/login"
status: 500
timestamp: "2022-06-01T19:37:00.757+00:00"

Comment: Don't call `super...` in the last line. Do the `response.sendError` instead, either with 401 or with your customized code.